# "undefined reference to" error when adding a new module in AOSP

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, android-source

I'm adding MTP module to the Recovery in Android source code. MTP is defined as a shared library (in path frameworks/av/media/mtp/Android.mk):

```
 LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=                                  \
           MtpServer.cpp  \
           other sources files                                                 
 LOCAL_MODULE:= libmtp
 LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DMTP_DEVICE -DMTP_HOST
 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libutils libcutils liblog libusbhost libbinder
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I want to use this module in Recovery, so I added a new module named minmtp in recovery path. The Android.mk is:

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE := libminmtp 
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    minmtp.cpp \
    MyMtpDatabase.cpp \

 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += \
     libmtp  
 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    frameworks/av/media/mtp
 LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DMTP_DEVICE -DMTP_HOST -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations 
 include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I added libminmtp into recovery in Android.mk:

```
 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libminmtp
 include $(LOCAL_PATH)/minmtp/Android.mk
```

It compiled successfully.

But when I used the class defined in minmtp.cpp in recovery.cpp, compilation will failed because of "undefined reference to" errors. The undefined reference functions are all defined in MtpServer.cpp and other source files of Android mtp module and used in minmtp.cpp.

I think it is because the linker counld not link libmtp.so, so how I should modify my code to make it work?

Comment: Most likely libc or libc++ shared libraries are not available in the recovery environment. Use the static libraries instead and see if that works.